# Is there a way to log number of retries made

Tags: python, module

I am trying to hit web-service which has Thread limit, i.e. if too many requests are made within seconds it will throw exception assuming it's an attack.

To resolve same we are using retrying module from python

Here is sample code

```
from retrying import retry


@retry(stop_max_attempt_number=10,wait_exponential_multiplier=1000, wait_exponential_max=10000)
def f():
    # Call web service
```

This works however there is no messages given which indicate it's working.

Is there a parameter / way by which we could use to log number of retries made, something like `waiting for 10 sec before next attempt`

Comment: Do you simply wanna avoid using other modules besides retry? How about utilizing the logging module?

Comment: @DemetriOS that will work where do you specify it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `wait_func` parameter for `retry` with a function that takes the number of attempts and the number of milliseconds of delay as parameters, and prints a message as desired:

```
from retrying import retry
import time

def wait(attempts, delay):
    print('Attempt #%d, retrying in %d seconds' % (attempts, delay // 1000))
    return delay

@retry(wait_func=wait)
def f():
    time.sleep(1)
    raise RuntimeError

f()
```

This outputs:

```
Attempt #1, retrying in 1 seconds
Attempt #2, retrying in 3 seconds
Attempt #3, retrying in 7 seconds
Attempt #4, retrying in 15 seconds
...
```

If you would like to use the exponential sleep option, however, you would have to instantiate your own `Retrying` instance and use a custom decorator to make use of it, so that your custom `wait` function can call the `exponential_sleep` method with your `Retrying` instance:

```
from retrying import Retrying

def wait(attempts, delay):
    print('Attempt #%d, retrying in %d seconds' % (attempts, delay // 1000))
    return retrying.exponential_sleep(attempts, delay)

retrying = Retrying(wait_func=wait, stop_max_attempt_number=10, wait_exponential_multiplier=1000, wait_exponential_max=10000)
custom_retry = lambda f: lambda *args, **kwargs: retrying.call(f, *args, **kwargs)

@custom_retry
def f():
    raise RuntimeError

f()
```

This outputs:

```
Attempt #1, retrying in 0 seconds
Attempt #2, retrying in 2 seconds
Attempt #3, retrying in 6 seconds
Attempt #4, retrying in 14 seconds
Attempt #5, retrying in 24 seconds
Attempt #6, retrying in 34 seconds
...
```

Comment: Thanks, This is good, 
But in this case wouldn't I have to write everything like max attempts, calculate exponential time etc.

Comment: Glad to be of help. The above is just to demonstrate how the `wait_func` parameter can be used. You can for sure still add the other parameters you already have.

Comment: By the way, can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? Let me know if you have more issues so I can further help.

Comment: It solves one and introduce another :)..
I just want to record attempts and leave default logic for retrying

Comment: I see. You're right that using the `wait_func` parameter would make `Retrying` not use the default logic. I've updated my answer so that it would explicitly use the `exponential_sleep` logic as you desire. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach to resolve it

after_attempts as another flag which could be used

```
def _after(attempt_number):
    print(attempt_number)


@retry(wait_fixed=100, stop_max_attempt_number=3, after_attempts=_after)
def _test_after():
    raise Exception("testing after_attempts handler")
```

But this is still under development and could be fetched using retrying `master` code not part of latest release : 1.3.3

Comment: Good to know that this functionality is going to be officially offered, although it's too bad that it seems that there's no `delay` argument passed to the `after_attempt` function, so your message won't be able to include how long it's going to wait.